# Adding an object to an array with exclusions

Tags: java, arrays

I have an homework to do.

I need to **add an object to an array**, but if the "catalogue number" is existing, I should add the quantity to the quantity variable of the object.

how do I check if the **_catalogueNumber of an item is already exists**.

**Example**

`public boolean addItem(FoodItem fooditem)`
how do I check if the catalogue number is already defined in one of the fooditem objects in the arrays?

Comment: By examining the existing objects in the array and comparing their catalogue numbers.

Comment: Iterate over the whole array and check it? Much smarter solution would be to use a `HashMap` instead of an array.

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem? Why didn't that work?

Comment: I just don't know how to write the code inside. I want to use the if statement, receiving the _catalogueNumber of the fooditem object received, and to look if there is already the same catalogueNumber in the array. how do I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have an `Arraylist<FoodItem>` and the `FoodItem` class which has a property `CatalogueNumber`:

```java
ArrayList<FoodItem> foodItems = ...;
for (FoodItem item : foodItems) {
    if (item.getCatalogueNumber() == newCatalogueNumber) {
        addItem(item);
    }
}
```